# Limitations of Windows 8 Desktop duplication using DXGI?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, remote-desktop, dxgi

I am working on a remote desktop application which works fine on windows 7 and its previous version. but In windows 8 mirror driver has removed so that we have to develop the same remote desktop feature using DXGI. I have read the documentation but I want to know **Is there any limitation of DXGI ?**

> If any one experience some limitation while creating desktop emulation
>   in windows 8 please share.